# Insert data in two tables using one controller and one view

Tags: cakephp, model, cakephp-2.3

I need help on this one. I have 2 tables. **item** and **item_picture**.  The Table with the name **item_picture** has a foregin key **item_id** that belongs to item. I have a wizard that  has fields  of item table like title, description, address, and fields of item_picture table like header_pic_1, header_pic_2, header_pic_3. bothe in one view.

Code is as below:

**Item** Model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
class Item extends AppModel {
public $name = 'Item';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $displayField = 'title';
    public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'blank' => array(
            'rule' => 'blank',
            'on' => 'create',
            ),
        ),
        'title' => array(
            'words' => array(
                'rule' => array('custom', '/[0-9A-Za-z\._-]/'),
                'message' => 'The Item name can only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
            ),
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'The Item name must not be empty.',
            ),
            'isUnique' => array(
                 'rule' => 'isUnique',
                 'message' => 'This Item name already exists.',
            ),
        ),
        'item_description' => array(
            'words' => array(
                'rule' => array('custom', '/[0-9A-Za-z\._-]/'),
                'message' => 'The Item description can only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
            ),
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Description can not be Empty',
            ),
        ),

        'media_path' => array(
            'uploadError' => array(
                'rule'=>'uploadError',
                'message' => 'The File Did NOT Upload. Please Try Again!',  
                'allowEmpty'=>false,
                'on' => 'create',               
            ),
            'processMediaUpload'=>array(
                'rule' =>'processMediaUpload',
                'message'=>'Uploading File Failed!',
                'allowEmpty'=>true,

            ),
        ),


        'address' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'You Should Put an Address',
            ),
        ),


        'user_id' => array(
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'Not Empty',
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ItemUser' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 */
    public $hasOne = array(

        'ItemPictures' => array(
            'className' => 'ItemPicture',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            ), 
        );



        //at the bottom of my Upload model        

}
```

**item_picture** Model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class ItemPicture extends AppModel {
public $name = 'ItemPicture';
    public $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $displayField = 'header_title';
    public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'blank' => array(
                'rule' => 'blank',
                'on' => 'create',
            ),
        ),
        'item_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                'message' => 'Choose the item this gallery belongs to?',
            ),
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
            ),
        ),
        'header_title' => array(
            'words' => array(
                'rule' => array('custom', '/[0-9A-Za-z\._-]/'),
                'message' => 'The Item name can only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
            ),
            'maxLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 100),
                'message' => 'The Header Title must not be longer than 100 characters.',
            ),
            'notEmpty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notEmpty'),
                'message' => 'The Header Title must not be empty.',
            ),
            'isUnique' => array(
                 'rule' => 'isUnique',
                 'message' => 'This Header Title already exists.',
            ),
        ),
        'parallax1_text' => array(
            'words' => array(
                'rule' => array('custom', '/[0-9A-Za-z\._-]/'),
                'message' => 'The Paralaxe name can only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
                'allowEmpty'=>TRUE,
            ),
            'maxLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 100),
                'message' => 'The Paralaxe name must not be longer than 100 characters.',
                'allowEmpty'=>TRUE,
            ),
        ),
        'parallax2_text' => array(
            'words' => array(
                'rule' => array('custom', '/[0-9A-Za-z\._-]/'),
                'message' => 'The Paralaxe name can only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
                'allowEmpty'=>TRUE,
            ),
            'maxLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 100),
                'message' => 'The Paralaxe name must not be longer than 100 characters.',
                'allowEmpty'=>TRUE,
            ),
        ),
        'parallax3_text' => array(
            'words' => array(
                'rule' => array('custom', '/[0-9A-Za-z\._-]/'),
                'message' => 'The Paralaxe name can only contain letters, numbers and spaces.',
                'allowEmpty'=>TRUE,
            ),
            'maxLength' => array(
                'rule' => array('maxLength', 100),
                'message' => 'The Paralaxe name must not be longer than 100 characters.',
                'allowEmpty'=>TRUE,
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'ItemItemPicture' => array(
            'className' => 'Item',
            'foreignKey' => 'item_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );


    /*******************************************************************
//////////   HERE IS THE OBJECT SLIDER PROCESS IMAGE ///////////////
*********************************************************************
      public function processHeaderPic1Upload($slidercheck=array()){
        // if there is no video uploaded return False 
          if(!is_uploaded_file($slidercheck['header_pic_1']['tmp_name'])){
                return FALSE;
              }
              // then if the file has been uploaded lets try to move it to it's destination 
              // We will put some logic to see if the move(uploading) fails
              if(!move_uploaded_file($slidercheck['header_pic_1']['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT. 'img/uploads/item/pictures/headslider/' . $slidercheck['header_pic_1']['name'])){
                  // if move didnt happened @return False
                  return FALSE;
                     }
                  //At this point the move is successfull and the model is going to save the data
                  //now we will overload the data cuz the file is in type array

                  $this->data[$this->alias]['header_pic_1']='uploads/item/pictures/headslider/' . $slidercheck['header_pic_1']['name'];
                  //@return TRUE since the operation was sucesfull
                  return TRUE;
          }
```

The view that i have build is this: **item** add.ctp

```
      <div class="content-header">
        &nbsp;<a id="menu-toggle" href="#" class="btn btn-info">Menu<i class="icon-reorder"></i></a><h1> Add Item</h1>
      </div>
  <div class="container">
<!-- Tabs -->
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Item', array('type'=>'file', 'id'=>'itemWizard','class'=>'gllpLatlonPicker')); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>
    <div id="wizard" class="swMain">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#step-1">
                <span class="stepNumber">1</span>
                <span class="stepDesc">
                   Generalle <br />
                   <small>Fill your account details</small>
                </span>
            </a></li>
          <li><a href="#step-2">
                <span class="stepNumber">2</span>
                <span class="stepDesc">
                  Galleria Header<br />
                   <small>Insert Gallery images</small>
                </span>
            </a></li>
          <li><a href="#step-3">
                <span class="stepNumber">3</span>
                <span class="stepDesc">
                   Parallaxe<br />
                   <small>Insert Parallaxe Images</small>
                </span>
             </a></li>
          <li><a href="#step-4">
                <span class="stepNumber">4</span>
                <span class="stepDesc">
                   Blocco 2<br />
                   <small>Fill your characteristice details</small>
                </span>
            </a></li>
          <li><a href="#step-5">
                <span class="stepNumber">5</span>
                <span class="stepDesc">
                   Blocco 3<br />
                   <small>Fill localization information</small>
                </span>
            </a></li>
          <li><a href="#step-6">
                <span class="stepNumber">6</span>
                <span class="stepDesc">
                   Venditori<br />
                   <small>Select item sellers</small>
                </span>
            </a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="step-1"> 
            <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 1: Generalle</h2>
            <table >       
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Item Title :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.title',array('class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_title','required'=>'required' ,'placeholder'=>'Item Title','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_title"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Item Description :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.seo_description',array('class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_seo_description','required'=>'required' ,'placeholder'=>'Item Description','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_seo_description"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Item Location:</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.item_location_id',array('empty'=>true,'class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_locationId','placeholder'=>'Item Description','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_locationId"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Keywords:</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.seo_keywords',array('class'=>'txtBox','placeholder'=>'Item Keywords','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"></td>
                </tr>  
           </table>               
        </div>
        <div id="step-2">
            <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 2: Header Gallery images</h2>  
            <table>        
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Header Title :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                       <?php echo $this->Form->input('ItemPicture.header_title',array('class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_header_title' ,'placeholder'=>'Header Title','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_header_title"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Header Slider Image (1) :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <div  id="attachment<?php echo 1;?>" >
                          <?php echo $this->Form->input('ItemPicture.header_pic_1',array('type'=>'file','class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_headerImage1' ,'label' => false,'div' => false));?>
                          <div  id="attachmentlink<?php echo 1;?>"></div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_headerImage1"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>                
                 <tr>
                      <td align="right">Header Slider Image (2) :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <div  id="attachment<?php echo 2;?>" >
                          <?php echo $this->Form->input('ItemPicture.header_pic_2',array('type'=>'file','class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_headerImage2' ,'label' => false,'div' => false));?>
                          <div  id="attachmentlink<?php echo 2;?>"></div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_headerImage2"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>                
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Header Slider Image (3) :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <div  id="attachment<?php echo 3;?>" >
                          <?php echo $this->Form->input('ItemPicture.header_pic_3',array('type'=>'file','class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_headerImage3','label' => false,'div' => false));?>
                          <div  id="attachmentlink<?php echo 3;?>"></div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_headerImage3"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
              <?php for($i=4; $i<7; $i++) { ?>
                  <tr>
                      <td align="right">Header Slider Image (<?php echo $i;  ?>) :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <div  id="attachment<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i !=4) echo "style='display:none;'";?> >
                          <?php echo $this->Form->input('ItemPicture.header_pic_'.$i,array('type'=>'file','class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_headerImage' . $i ,'label' => false,'div' => false));?>
                          <div  id="attachmentlink<?php echo $i;?>"  <?php if($i==6) echo "style='display:none;'";?>>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="show('attachment<?php echo $i+1;?>'); hide('attachmentlink<?php echo $i;?>');">Add More</a>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_headerImage<?php echo $i; ?>"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                 </tr>
              <?php  } ?>                                     
           </table>        
        </div>    

        <div id="step-3">
            <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 3: Parallaxe Images</h2>  
            <table>      
             <?php for ($i= 1; $i <   4; $i++) { ?>         
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Paralaxe Text :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                      <?php  echo $this->Form->input('ItemPicture.parallax'.$i.'_text', array('class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_parallax'.$i.'text' ,'label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_parallax<?php echo $i; ?>text"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Parallaxe Picture :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                      <?php  echo $this->Form->input('ItemPicture.parallax'.$i.'_pic', array('type'=>'file','class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_parallax'.$i.'pic','label' => false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_parallax<?php echo $i; ?>pic"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Parallaxe Pattern :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <?php  echo $this->Form->input('ItemPicture.parallax'.$i.'_pattern' , array('type'=>'checkbox','class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_parallax'.$i.'patern','label' => false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_parallax<?php echo $i; ?>patern"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <hr />
              <?php  } ?>   
           </table>                                 
        </div> 

        <div id="step-4">
            <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 4: Bloco 2</h2>  
            <table>       
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Descrizione Intervento * :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.item_description',array('class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_description','required'=>'required' ,'placeholder'=>'Item Description','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_description"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Item Characteristics :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.item_characteristic_id',array('empty'=>true,'class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_characteristic' ,'placeholder'=>'Item Description','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_characteristic"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Video Path :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.video_path',array('type'=>'text','class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_video' ,'placeholder'=>'Paste here video path','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_video"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Media Path :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.media_path',array('type'=>'file','id'=>'imgInp','required'=>'required' ,'label'=>false)); ?>
                      <?php echo "<img id=\"showImg\" src=\"#\" alt=\" \" style=\"max-height:100px; class=\"img-rounded img-responsive\" \" />" ;  ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_imgImp"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Broshure Path :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.brochure_path',array('type'=>'file','id'=>'item_broshure','required'=>'required' ,'label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_broshure"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>                                          
           </table>                       
        </div> 

        <div id="step-5">
            <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 5: Blocco 3</h2>  
            <table>     
                <tr>
                      <td align="right" style="width:15%">Descrizione Localizzazione * :</td>
                      <td align="left" style="width:70%">
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.location_description',array('class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'location_description','required'=>'required' ,'placeholder'=>'Item Description','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left" style="width:15%"><span id="msg_location_description"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                      <td align="right" style="width:15%">address :</td>
                      <td align="left" style="width:70%">
                        <?php  echo "<input type=\"button\" class=\"gllpSearchButton\" value=\"search\">"; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.address',array('id' => 'address','class'=>'gllpSearchField','label'=>false)); ?>
                        <?php   echo "<input type=\"button\" class=\"gllpUpdateButton\" value=\"update map\">"; ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->input('Zoom',array('type'=>'text', 'class'=>'gllpZoom', 'value'=>'3'));   ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left" style="width:15%"><span id="msg_address"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                      <td align="right" style="width:15%">Google Maps :</td>
                      <td style="width:85%" colspan="2">
                     <?php  echo "<div class=\"gllpMap\">Google Maps</div>"; ?>
                      </td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                      <td align="right" style="width:15%">longitude :</td>
                      <td align="left" style="width:70%">
                      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.longitude',array('class'=>'txtBox','id' => 'longitude','class'=>'gllpLongitude','placeholder'=>'longitude','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td style="width:15%"><span id="msg_item_longitude"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>
                      <td align="right" style="width:15%">latitude:</td>
                      <td align="left" style="width:70%">
                      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.latitude',array('class'=>'txtBox','id' => 'latitude','placeholder'=>'latitude','class'=>'gllpLatitude','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td style="width:15%"><span id="msg_item_latitude"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>                                         
           </table>                                 
        </div>

        <div id="step-6">
            <h2 class="StepTitle">Step 6: Venditori</h2>  
            <table>    
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Venditoro 1 :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.first_seller_id',array('empty'=>true,'class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_seller1','required'=>'required','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_seller1"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>               
                <tr>
                      <td align="right">Venditoro 2 :</td>
                      <td align="left">
                      <?php echo $this->Form->input('Item.second_seller_id',array('empty'=>true,'class'=>'txtBox','id'=>'item_seller2','required'=>'required','label'=>false)); ?>
                      </td>
                      <td align="left"><span id="msg_item_seller2"></span>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>                                         
           </table>                                 
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Add Item'),array('class'=>'btn btn-success','after'=>$this->Html->link('Cancel',array('controller'=>'items','action'=>'index'),array('class'=>'btn btn-default')))); ?>
  <?php  echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
<!-- End SmartWizard Content -->   
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#showImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){readURL(this);
    });
</script>

<script>
function show(target){document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';}
function hide(target){document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none'; }
</script>
```

** **Solution for the problem:**

```
function add() {
  $this->layout='item_add';
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
     if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->ItemPicture->create();
            // FOR HEADER SLIDER
        for($i=1;$i<7;$i++)
            { $dir = 'img/uploads/item/pictures/headslider/';
              if(empty($this->data['ItemPicture']['header_pic_'.$i]['name'])){
                unset($this->request->data['ItemPicture']['header_pic_'.$i]);
              }       
              if(!empty($this->data['ItemPicture']['header_pic_'.$i]['name']))
              {   
              $allowedExts = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif');
              $extension=strtolower(end(explode(".", $this->data['ItemPicture']['header_pic_'.$i]['name']))); 
              $file=$this->data['ItemPicture']['header_pic_'.$i]; 
                if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
                {
                if ($file["error"] <= 0) {   
                  move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $dir  . mktime().$file['name']);
                  $this->request->data['ItemPicture']['header_pic_'.$i] = mktime().$file['name'];
                }
              }
            }         
          }

            // FOR PARRALAXE
        for($i=1;$i<4;$i++){ 
            $dirparallaxe = 'img/uploads/item/pictures/parallaxe/';
            if(empty($this->data['ItemPicture']['parallax'.$i.'_pic']['name'])) {
                unset($this->request->data['ItemPicture']['parallax'.$i.'_pic']);
              }
            if(!empty($this->data['ItemPicture']['parallax'.$i.'_pic']['name'])) {
                $allowedExts = array('jpeg', 'png', 'jpg', 'gif');
                $extension=strtolower(end(explode(".", $this->data['ItemPicture']['parallax'.$i.'_pic']['name'])));
                $parallaxe=$this->data['ItemPicture']['parallax'.$i.'_pic']; 
                if(in_array($extension, $allowedExts)){
                    if ($parallaxe["error"] <= 0) {   
                        move_uploaded_file($parallaxe['tmp_name'], WWW_ROOT . $dirparallaxe  . mktime().$parallaxe['name']);
                        $this->request->data['ItemPicture']['parallax'.$i.'_pic'] = mktime().$parallaxe['name'];
                    }
                 }
              }
            }  

            unset($this->ItemPicture->validate['item_id']);
            $this->request->data['Item']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if($this->Item->save($this->request->data)){
            $this->request->data['ItemPicture']['item_id'] = $this->Item->getLastInsertId();
            if ($this->ItemPicture->save($this->data)) {        
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
                } else {
                 $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
                } // END OF ItemPicture->save
            } else {
             $this->Session->setFlash(__('The profile could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
        } // END OF Item->save
     } 
  } 

    //$this->loadModel("Item");
    $itemLocations = $this->Item->ItemLocation->find('list');
    $itemCharacteristics = $this->Item->ItemCharacteristic->find('list');
    $firstSellers = $this->Item->FirstSeller->find('list');
    $secondSellers = $this->Item->SecondSeller->find('list');
    $users = $this->Item->ItemUser->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('itemLocations', 'itemCharacteristics', 'firstSellers', 'secondSellers', 'users')); 
    //if the user is admin or superadmin, show all on dropdown
    if ( AuthComponent::user('role')==='admin' ||AuthComponent::user('role')==='superadmin' ){ 
        $items = $this->ItemPicture->ItemItemPicture->find('list');
        } else {// else if the user is author, show only item created by him.
        $items = $this->ItemPicture->ItemItemPicture->find('list', array('conditions' => array('ItemItemPicture.user_id' => AuthComponent::user('id'))));           
    }
    $this->set(compact('items'));     

} // END OF ADD ACTION
```

So the procesing need to be done in the **ItemPicturesController** , since its holding the foregin kew to the item table. and there i use

```
public $uses = array('ItemPicture','Item');
```

to use bothe models in itemPictureController and now is doing what i want.

Comment: this question has been asked before

Comment: it has but i didnt get any answer, plus i posted the code so you could be more clear what it is and what i want...:/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read the chapter in the book about saving your data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html), your case is well [explained there](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array).

Your form must generate that structure (example):

```
$data = array(
    'Item' => array('title' => 'My first article'),
    'ItemPicture' => array(
        array('image' => 'test'),
        array('image' => 'test2'),
        array('image' => 'test3'),
    ),
);
```

You'll have to name your form inputs for that like:

```
$this->Form->input('Image.' . $i . ' . 'image');
```

Your controller add method looks not good, it should go into a model method as well. You want fat models, skinny controllers.

Comment: Thanx for your answer but i managed to solve it :) i will post the answer above.